# android:when run onLoadFinished in orientation change

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

I am using from AsyncLoader in my app .
I want know onLoadFinished run after which method of my fragment during orientation change?

I show a dialog when loader run first time

```
@Override
    public Loader<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>> onCreateLoader(int id,Bundle bundle)
    {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(SendRequestLoader.ShowDialog);
        return loader;
    }
```

I add listarray to my adapter

```
@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>> loader,ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> list)
    {
        Log.e("", "---onLoadFinished---");
        if(list!=null)
        Log.e("before","-------adapter.size()----"+adapter.getCount());
        if(list!=null)
        {
         int count=list.size();
         for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
         {
            adapter.add(list.get(i));   
         }
        }
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(((SendRequestLoader)loader).getMessage());
        if(list!=null)
        Log.e("","-------list.size()----"+list.size());
        Log.e("after","-------adapter.size()----"+adapter.getCount());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>> loader) 
    {
    }
```

I save dialog state for show dialog in orientation change.but i am not sure onLoadFinished method can  run after onSaveInstanceState method or no and am I  using a right way for manage my loader?

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if(isshowingDialog)
        outState.putBoolean("isshow",true);
    else
        outState.putBoolean("isshow",false);
    outState.putParcelable("parcle", new Parcable(adapter.getArrayList()));
}
```

Comment: Could you give more details? I read your post many times and not understand your doubt.

Comment: I want show and dismiss dialog before and after data loading.but i dont know if i change orientation when onLoadFinished run .can it run after onSaveInstanceState or no

Comment: I hope help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23893185/575643

Comment: -1 because abandoned the question!

Answer (score 0):

> Based on your comment:
>   [android:when run onLoadFinished in orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841474/androidwhen-run-onloadfinished-in-orientation-change?noredirect=1#comment36688007_23841474)

To not loose dialog state when screen changes the orientation you should do some staff.

First in `AndroidManifest.xml` you gonna set the config changes of `Activity`:

```
<activity
    android:name="my.app.pkg.MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
</activity>
```

After that you gonna override the `onConfigurationChanged` method in your `Activity` class to not handle anything when this happen:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged( final Configuration newConfig ) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged( newConfig );
}
```

At here your `Activity` will not be restarted when user rotate the device and orientation changes, and you not will lost your async staff.