# Android run method after orientation is complete

Tags: android, event-handling, screen-rotation

I have some code that will run when the [orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841474/androidwhen-run-onloadfinished-in-orientation-change):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setVideoSize();
    _videoSurfaceView.changeCameraDisplaySize();
}

private void setVideoSize() {
    //Get the dimensions of the video
    int videoWidth = _videoSurfaceView.getCamera().getParameters().getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo().width;
    int videoHeight = _videoSurfaceView.getCamera().getParameters().getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo().height;
    float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;

    // Get the width of the screen
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;

    // Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = _videoSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
        lp.width = screenWidth;
        lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
    } else {
        lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
        lp.height = screenHeight;
    }
    // Commit the layout parameters
    _videoSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

This is called when a rotation occurs, but **I need to run setVideoSize() after the rotation is complete**. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead try running your method in `onResume()`. Which is called when activity is resumed from a paused state.

Note that when you change your orientation activity gets re-created thus `onResume()` will be called also.